# How to get "historical" shapefile (road, waterways, railways, etc.) of India?

Tags: data-request, india, openstreetmap, geospatial

I am interested in looking at future trends in linear developmental activities in India and how they may impact the integrity of wildlife corridors. Basically, I need to do trend analysis over the past 20 years (from 1995) and predict the kind of changes that might come in the next 5 years. For this, one of the requirements is getting historical data of roads, railways, waterways etc. and see how they've changed over the years. I already have the latest shapefile of these from OpenStreetMap (OSM). Is there any opensource from where I can get this information?

Comment: Did you find this data? I would be interested in viewing the same as well.